# Android MapView#addView()

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm using my MapView addView() method in order to add an animated view to it.

When i'm doing this i already have some OverlayItems in my MapView.

when the addView() method is called, all my markers are disappearing...

any idea why ?

```
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        app.setMapActivity((Map)context);
        if (!isAnimating)
        {
            if (isNewMarkers(canvas, mapView, shadow))
                isAnimating = true;
            else
                finishDraw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        }
    }   

    private boolean isNewMarkers(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        boolean isNewMarkers = false;
        synchronized (newMarkers) 
        {
            Iterator<OverlayItem> iterator = newMarkers.iterator();         
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {               
                OverlayItem overlayItem = iterator.next();              
                isNewMarkers = true;                
                animateMarker(canvas, mapView, shadow, overlayItem.getMarker(0), overlayItem.getPoint(),!iterator.hasNext());
            }           
        }       
        fullMapOverlays.addAll(newMarkers);
        newMarkers.clear();
        populate();
        return isNewMarkers;
    }           

    private void animateMarker(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, Drawable marker, GeoPoint point, boolean setListener) 
    {               
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(app.getMainActivity(), R.anim.map_marker_animiation);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) View.inflate(app.getMainActivity(), R.layout.marker_animation, null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(marker); 

//add view function 
        mapView.addView(imageView, 0, new MapView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, point, MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER));           
        if (setListener)
            animation.setAnimationListener(new MarkerAnimationListener(canvas, mapView, shadow));
        imageView.startAnimation(animation);
    }


    public void finishDraw(Canvas canvas, final MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
    {
        mapOverlays = createOverlayItems(mapView);
        populate();
        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);        
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        if (mapView.getChildCount()>0)
        {
            mapView.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mapView.removeAllViews();                   
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private class MarkerAnimationListener implements AnimationListener
    {

        private MapView mapView;
        private Canvas canvas;
        private boolean shadow;

        public MarkerAnimationListener(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
        {
            this.mapView = mapView;
            this.canvas = canvas;
            this.shadow = shadow;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {           
            isAnimating = false;
            finishDraw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the overlays return if you swipe or zoom around the MapView or are the gone permanently after adding your view?

Comment: my function runs inside the override draw() method so if you're going there its not the issue :).. will update my question

Comment: i've tried to Log it and right after the addView all the overlayItems are disappear.. and as you can see when the animation is finished i'm removing the view and drawing the overlay items